# MongoDB - using $count inside a $facet stage for the calculations

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection and I want to get the total number of documents and use that amount in a `$facet` to calculate the 95th percentile (in the example below, the duration for each document is defined as finish_time - start_time).

Let's say I have these documents:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("178768747638364736373637"),
    "start_time": ISODate("2019-02-03T12:00:00.000Z"),
    "finish_time": ISODate("2019-02-03T12:01:00.000Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("266747364736363536353555"),
    "start_time": ISODate("2019-02-03T12:00:00.000Z"),
    "finish_time": ISODate("2019-02-03T12:03:00.000Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("367463536453623546353625"),
    "start_time": ISODate("2019-02-03T12:00:00.000Z"),
    "finish_time": ISODate("2019-02-03T12:08:00.000Z")
  }
]
```

I'm expecting this output:

```
[
  {
    "Percentile95Index": 2.8499999999999996,
    "_id": ObjectId("178768747638364736373637"),
    "duration": 60,
    "totalCount": 3
  },
  {
    "Percentile95Index": 2.8499999999999996,
    "_id": ObjectId("266747364736363536353555"),
    "duration": 180,
    "totalCount": 3
  },
  {
    "Percentile95Index": 2.8499999999999996,
    "_id": ObjectId("367463536453623546353625"),
    "duration": 480,
    "totalCount": 3
  }
]
```

So I did this (https://mongoplayground.net/p/xtHLHouzNQr):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    // Since total count will always be a one-document result, I need $facet to run multiple aggregation pipelines and then merge results.
    $facet: {
      totalCount: [
        {
          $count: "value"
        }
      ],
      pipelineResults: [
        {
          "$project": {
            duration: {
              "$divide": [
                {
                  "$subtract": [
                    "$finish_time",
                    "$start_time"
                  ]
                },
                1000
              ]// duration is in seconds

            },
            Percentile95Index: {
              "$multiply": [
                0.95,
                "$totalCount.value" // HERE I'D LIKE TO ACCESS THE TOTAL_COUNT!!!!
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$totalCount"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$pipelineResults"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$pipelineResults",
          {
            totalCount: "$totalCount.value"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see, inside the `Percentile95Index` field, I'd like to access the `totalCount.value` but it's not accessible there and I can't figure out how to do it.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my opinion, I don't think the `$facet` stage is needed based on your scenario. *(Would be great if you can share the reason to use `$facet`)*.

To count the total documents in the collection and render the count value to each document, you may look for [`$setWindowFields`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/).

1. `$setWindowFields` - Render the `totalCount` field with the value of the total number of documents in the collection.
2. `$project` - Decorate the output documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      output: {
        totalCount: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      totalCount: 1,
      duration: {
        "$divide": [
          {
            "$subtract": [
              "$finish_time",
              "$start_time"
            ]
          },
          1000
        ]
      },
      Percentile95Index: {
        "$multiply": [
          0.95,
          "$totalCount"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sHv-KAl1fTi)